# Mathematica FindRoot solve equation

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a task to solve equation system with `FindRoot`:

`a*x+b*y^2-c*x^2=a-b`, `a*x^2+b*y^2+b*x-cy=b+c` , where a = 10, b = 10, c = 6;

I'm very(!) new to Mathematica and have one day to get to know it.

Any comments on how to solve that equation will be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html

Comment: Will this be correct:
FindRoot[{a*x + b*y^2 - c*x^2 == a - b, a*x^2 + b*y^2 + b*x - c*y == b + c}, {{x, 1}, {y, 1}}]

It gives me result, but I don't know if it is correct one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This starts searching for root at `x = 0` and `y = 0`

```
eq = {a*x + b*y^2 - c*x^2 == a - b, a*x^2 + b*y^2 + b*x - c*y == b + c}
param = {a -> 10, b -> 10, c -> 6}
result = FindRoot[eq /. param, {x, 0}, {y, 0}]
```

This only gives you 1 of the two Real solutions. `Solve` will give you both (and even some solutions with Complex numbers). To test it:

```
eq /. param /. result
```

This returns `(True, True)` so you know you've found the correct root.

To find the solution graphically, use `ContourPlot`:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[eq /. param], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the version with Solve/NSolve

```
NSolve[{a*x + b*y^2 - c*x^2 == a - b, 
        a*x^2 + b*y^2 + b*x - c*y == b + c} /.  {a -> 10, b -> 10, c -> 6},
       {x, y}]
```

It will give the 4 solutions.  If you use Solve instead of NSolve you will have a (large) closed form of each component of each solution.

If you need more digits for the solution, add at the end of the NSolve command the option `WorkingPrecision->30` (or any other number of digits. These are quadratics, they can computed to any precision necessary).